# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'

Tags: python, importerror, catboost

I'm trying to build a machine learning model and when I import the `catboost` I get an error

when I run: `from catboost import CatBoostRegressor`

I get: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'`

Maybe because I can only install the old version 0.1.1 of catboost

i use pip install catboost

and i get: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost (from versions: 0.1.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost

Comment: Sounds like you've got an out-of-date version of `catboost`, or possibly one of its dependencies. You didn't show the full stack trace, so we can't tell exactly where the problem is. (`collections` itself is *not* the problem. Don't try to "update" that - it's a stdlib package. If you try to update it, at best, you'll do nothing, and at worst, you'll screw things up even more.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: when i try to istall catboost it give me this : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost (from versions: 0.1.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost

Comment: You need to edit your question with more information. Like what commands you are doing to install the package. Venturing a guess, your Python is 3.10 or later in which case `Sequence` is in `collections.abc`. I'm guessing your version of catboost is old enough not to account for this.

Comment: i use pip install catboost and im using python latest version with all the other packes that are necessary for installing catboost

Comment: If you are just running `pip install catboost` by itself and it is trying to get 0.1.1 you are maybe not pulling from the main PyPI. That isn't the latest version. You may try `pip install --upgrade catboost`, or specifying a newer version explicitly.

Comment: yeah i tried evrything but sill can't install catboost latest version

Answer (score -2):

I installed conda and run jupyter notebook from it and it solved the probleme

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).